# What's a Good example of Practle Serialation lib Usage

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, emurgo

Okay so I have used an older version of the library by emerugo. And want some examples of the use of the newer version just to make sure I'm not missing anything important.

Can someone point me the most upto date docs?

Answer (score 2):

I find this react example very useful as it pretty much shows all cases you may want to use the serialization lib.

[https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector.git](https://github.com/dynamicstrategies/cardano-wallet-connector/blob/master/src/App.js)

Comment: have you got somthing with some more documentation?

Comment: Perhaps cardano's developer docs?
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/cardano-serialization-lib/overview

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark my response as answer if it is satisfying your question :)

Comment: Actually, it's not really a satisfying answer so I'm planning on trying this out myself and posting the findings as a new answer.  I gave you the only upvote so far just because I appreciate you trying to help, if your answer were satisfying I would have given you the tick at the same time.  So apologies but I'm afread I cant do that right now.

Comment: Please specify your question then, bc the first link I provided shows plenty of examples how to use the serialization lib and the second provides a walk through for common examples with a demo available.

I am not sure what else you're looking for?

Comment: Another resource that might be interesting is: https://github.com/Berry-Pool/lucid
It's an abstraction layer on top of the serialization lib